# C# equivalent of pydoc

Tags: c#, documentation, pydoc

Visual Studio is not present at my work location and I am using Notepad++ for the development. I am aware of MSDN, but I want to browse the documentation from command line like in Python.

In Python, you can browse the documentation for a module or function or like this:

```
$ pydoc raw_input
```

gives

```
Help on built-in function raw_input in module __builtin__:

raw_input(...)
    raw_input([prompt]) -> string

    Read a string from standard input.  The trailing newline is stripped.
    If the user hits EOF (Unix: Ctl-D, Windows: Ctl-Z+Return), raise EOFError.
    On Unix, GNU readline is used if enabled.  The prompt string, if given,
    is printed without a trailing newline before reading.
```

I want to find out if there is something similar for C# where I can do the following:

```
$ doc ReadLine
```

and I get some help on the Console.ReadLine method.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no command line/console help viewer for MSDN content.

The closest you can get (that I know of), is the [Package This](http://packagethis.codeplex.com/) project that will download MSDN content and make a CHM out of it.